# Take second line from string where starts from - till

Tags: c#, string

I need to take the *second line* from `string` which starts from `'\r'` till the next `'\r'` character.

Here is an examle from my string

```
string str = "@b\r210.190\r\000.000\r\n";
```

I need to take value `210.190` but *without* `'\r'` characters inside.

Comment: Simply `Split` by `\r` and take the second item of the resulting array.

Comment: Please check what i found, and tell me if i need something that i should careful before i will use it: str.Split(new char[]{ '\r','\n' },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[1];

Comment: Looks good - why don't you simply run it and inspect it using the debugger, or even better: Create a unit test for the method containg this code.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, as i can see it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [also](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52309393/2932052) suggest to use the [*Split* method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netframework-4.7.2), but I think that Dmitry Bychenko's answer could be phrased simpler:

```
string result = str.Split('\r')[1];
```

Here is an online demo: https://ideone.com/6Kedjj

As Dmitry Bychenko [explained](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52307484/take-second-line-from-string-where-starts-from-till/52309393?noredirect=1#comment91566400_52309393) this may cause the creation of a long array even if you are only interested in the second item. This may be prevented by limiting the output to three matches:

```
string result = str.Split(new char[] {'\r'}, 3)[1];
```

The first parameter looks complicated but is in the same array of chars with just one element that is in fact used in the first version. (for completeness the updated demo: https://ideone.com/TimaHP)

Comment: IMO, this is discouraged [as mentioned by Dmitry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52307484/take-second-line-from-string-where-starts-from-till#comment91566400_52309393) in the comment. If the string is malformed this might throw an `OutOfRangeException` exception. Why would you prefer something that might misbehave before something that has a clear error handling?

Comment: @Default FirstOrDefault() does not have clear error handling, it simply returns null if there is no element. The function here is to get data out of a defined string. If the caller gives null instead of the string, both methods fail with a NullReferenceException -> no clear error handling?

Answer (score 5):

Try using `Split`:

```
  string str = "@b\r210.190\r\000.000\r\n";

  string result = str
    .Split(new char[] { '\r' }, 3)  // split on 3 items at most
    .Skip(1)                        // skip the 1st item 
    .FirstOrDefault();              // take the second item if exists (null if not)
```

**Edit:** In case of *arbitrary* `string`s (which can well be `null` or contain *1 billion* characters) I suggest `IndexOf` and `Substring` (since `Split` creates an *array* which can be *unwanted*):

```
  int from = str == null ? -1 : str.IndexOf('\r');
  int length = from < 0 ? -1 : str.IndexOf('\r', from + 1) - from;

  string result = length >= 0 ? str.Substring(from + 1, length) : null;
```

Comment: @Wolf: in case of *very long* initial string splittinfg into `3` items only will be faster: `Split('\r')` can well create array of `100000` items; `Skip(1).FirstOrDefault()` returns `null` without throwing exception in case the original string has `1` item only: `"abc".Split('\r')[1]` throws `OutOfRangeException`

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Would you, even for normal cases, prefer to use this code, or should one use the seemingly [obvious simple version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52309614/2932052)?

Comment: @Wolf: if I implement a `private` method which operates with strings guaranteed to be *short* and have at least 2 items (if I know thee source of such strings) I'll prefer your solution. When context is unknown I prefer to be on a safe side.

Comment: Thanks a lot. In production code that is built on top of a lot of second matches, I guess, you have a specialized function to keep the code compact ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could also use Regex pattern matching for that. Method `Regex.Match` searches for first occurrence of the specified regular expression:

```
string str = "@b\r210.190\r\000.000\r\n";

var resultString = Regex.Match(str, @"(?<=\r).+?(?=\r)").Value;

Console.WriteLine(resultString + " " + resultString.Contains("\r"));
```

Output: `210.190 False`

Comment: interesting approach, whereas the (in general cool) check for `\r` in the output is probably (not) as efficient as the extraction itself ;)